# Using BindingList(Of Object) - CodeDom late binding

Tags: c#, vb.net, data-binding

I am trying to use a BindingList with an object created at runtime using CodeDom.  But I think I have run into a Late Binding wall.  Creating the Type and DLL all works well and I can access the properties and so can intellisense.  But  the BindingList or DataGridView control doesnt work with it.

Since my new Type is not known until runtime after the CodeDom methods, I cant do this:

```
Private myBList As BindingList(Of myDomType)
```

But this does not work:

```
myBList = New BindingList(Of Object)
...
Dim obj = CreateNewDomObject(values())   ' values passed to the constructor
myBList.Add(obj)                         ' the DGV doesnt show the data
```

`Of Object` apparently just wont work wvwn with known types:

```
myBList = New BindingList(Of Object)
...
myBList.Add(New Foo)                        ' Foo is a known Type
```

Apparently DGV or the BindingList do not bother with a late bound object.  So I tried this:

```
Public MustInherit Class myObject
   ... 2 trivial properties
End Class
```

Then changed the CodeDom generator to make the created CodeDom class inherit from myObject.  This was to provide a concrete Type for binding and to allow:

```
myBList = New BindingList(Of myObject)      ' a concrete type
...
Dim obj = CreateNewDomObject(values())      ' returns a myObject type   
myBList.Add(obj)
```

This compiles without late binding warnings, but the data still isnt showing in the DGV. I also tried to set/reset the DGV DataDisplayNames after there was a legit `myObject` in the list.  I can understand this not working when it was simply Object, but not why it doesnt work when the CodeDom Type inherits from a known type.

So, can something like this be done (and if so, what is the trick)?  Is there an Attribute I could use in the CodeDom source or a trick with the TypeDescriptor?

Comment: Did you try any other grid? DataGridView is not the best control on the market. It may not support all of that complex stuff. Is there any reason you avoid using a DataTable descendant?

Comment: Well, well.  I would have bet Big Bucks that the issue was in the DGV, because the BindingList is just a fancy List after all.  I grudgingly tried to use a DataTable in place of the B-List - Bingo, it worked.  Apparently this is in part because when the DataTable is the source, its Column Names are used as the DataDisplayNames (added "X" to them resulted in a blank grid).  So, that will simplify things a lot, I not only don't need a BindingList I dont need to CodeDOM component either.  If you'd like to post an answer I will accept since you sent me down that path.  Thanks for the nudge!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a DataTable descendant class. I used this approach a lot in production environment previously with a 3rd party grid control - it worked fine. Should also work with DataGridView.